# How to store file descriptor in a struct

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor

I have a program which spawns multiple children. The number of children spawned is unknown as it relies on user input. Every child and parent must have two pipes connecting to them. However, I want to access the file descriptors of the pipes to be able to read and write to the specific child using the pipes in future functions. I have looked into making the file descriptor as `fd[i][2]`, `i` being the specific child that pipe is referring to. I am aware I will have to dynamically allocate the file descriptors as the array is increasing in size every time the user creates a new child. I know that every child will have an array being `fd[2][2]`.  My goal is to store the file descriptors in a struct so I can access them in other functions. But I am struggling with how to allocate the memory for the file descriptors. I don't really have code to show as it is more of a knowledge-based question.
What I have is a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int* fd[2][2];
}FileDesc;
```

Comment: Why `int *fd[2][2]`?  Remove the `*` — you're storing `int` values, and the pointers waste space and complicate things without providing any benefit.  You'll want a dynamic array of `FileDesc` structures, not a dynamic array within the structure.  Again, that makes things a whole lot simpler.

Comment: The member of the struct should be `int fd[2][2];`, and you should allocate an array of the structures. For example `FileDesc *fileDescArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(FileDesc));` allocates memory for an array of 10 structures. You can expand the array later with `realloc`, if needed.

Comment: @user3386109 the struct I have set up already is storing another argument in it, which is an array of integers, is it possible to also store the file descriptors, as an integer array in the same struct, without storing it as an array of structures?  I just currently have a few structs made and want to avoid creating another one

Comment: Sure. Just put `int fd[2][2];` in the other structure.

Comment: I suggest storing the two pipes in different variables to make the roles clearer, e.g. `int parent_to_child[2]; int child_to_parent[2];`

Comment: @Barmar I see the practically in this, and actually might do this, however would you be able to show me how i can allocate memory for this? preferably not for an array of structs

Comment: You should be allocating an array of structures.  Each structure encapsulates the data for one child.  The array of structures stores the info for your set of child processes.  Trying to make a single structure encapsulate multiple arrays is an abuse of the concept of a structure.